# build sql using excel how to change dd/mm/yyyy into yyymmdd value

Tags: sql, excel

I have a task to create some sql update statements in excel but have this annoying situation where the SQLServer DB stored dates as integers.  Yes weird but need to deal with it, cant change it.  here is my statement:

```
=CONCATENATE("update table SET enrollDate=", J5,", passDate='", K5,"', approved=", G5," WHERE coursePeopleID=", A5, " ;")
```

so J5 an K5 there values are dd/mm/yyyy how can I make sure the value is yyyymmdd?  I have tried a custom format on the cells whch does show  yyyymmdd correctly in excel but when I look at the output of the above it gived me this:

```
update table SET enrollDate=41642, passDate='41766', approved=1 WHERE coursePeopleID=71653 ;
```

The values which are behind the enrollDate and the passDate above are:
     41642 = 20140103
     41766 = 20140507
Is this some kind of serial date format.  What can I wrap around this:

```
enrollDate=", J5,
```

to make sure 03/01/2014 is 20140103?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the `TEXT` worksheet function to convert it to text in a certain format. E.g. `TEXT(J5,"yyyymmdd")`